# Dropbox with limited content on a different computer

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox Pro account which I use on several devices.

Now I would like to setup Dropbox on a computer where other people have access but only sync a part of my files.

In other words: a foreign computer where a part (one or more folders) of my dropbox is synced.

I know what I could install Dropbox with "selective" sync, but for a user it would only need a couple of clicks to activate the other folders.

Another solution would be to buy another Dropbox Pro account and share the files with this, but this would imply to pay the double.

Any other cheaper solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the share option would be the answer.

https://www.dropbox.com/help/topics/sharing_files_and_folders

You could also set what the users whom you shared to can do to the folders.

In short, you can let people edit, delete and view the folder and files according to your needs.

Comment: Yes but then I will have to pay for a second pro account. My question is if there is a cheaper way.

Comment: But if I am not mistaken, the other user does not need to have a pro account to be able to sync the selective folders.

Comment: I tried and I get the error that I don't have enough space on the second account (the free one)

Comment: How many GB's are we talking about?

Comment: Around 20GB (more than the free quota)

Comment: Sounds like there is no other way that I know since the size of the folder is around 20GB. One way I know is that if you have a friend with a brand new HP device that comes with a promotion of Extra 25GB Dropbox space or an ASUS device which also comes with an extra Dropbox space, you're good to go! But unfortunately, the space given only lasts for 12 months if I'm not mistaken. Do take note that there are T&C applied for these promotions. [Wish I could just give my acc to you but I kinda need it for future use too.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/32LVe.jpg)

Comment: You can share your folder and they can access it via web (dropbox.com). Recipient should not be logged into a Dropbox account.